# Migration errors & rollback attempt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, migration, rollback

Currently making a reddit-type website and found (for whatever reason) my migration to create comments no longer existed after working the other "moving parts." I proceeded to generate a new comment migration and was greeted with a nice wall of *"StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled: [...]"* I researched rolling back/deleting migrations to fix my problem but can't seem to get anywhere. Below is the result of my effort to repair my app before I got too scared of ruining it completely.

```
Kristoffers-MBP:bloccit Juice$ rake db:migrate:status

database: /Users/Juice/code/bloccit/db/development.sqlite3

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150315080918  Create advertisements
   up     20150321042053  Devise create users
   up     20150323040831  Add role to users
   up     20150328164720  Create topics
   up     20150328170242  Add topic to posts
   up     20150405212530  Add avatar to users
   up     20150406044601  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20150412173406  Create comments

Kristoffers-MBP:bloccit Juice$ rake db:rollback
Kristoffers-MBP:bloccit Juice$ rake db:migrate:status

database: /Users/Juice/code/bloccit/db/development.sqlite3

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150315080918  Create advertisements
   up     20150321042053  Devise create users
   up     20150323040831  Add role to users
   up     20150328164720  Create topics
   up     20150328170242  Add topic to posts
   up     20150405212530  Add avatar to users
   up     20150406044601  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20150412173406  Create comments

Kristoffers-MBP:bloccit Juice$ rake db:rollback
Kristoffers-MBP:bloccit Juice$ rake db:migrate:status

database: /Users/Juice/code/bloccit/db/development.sqlite3

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150315080918  Create advertisements
   up     20150321042053  Devise create users
   up     20150323040831  Add role to users
   up     20150328164720  Create topics
   up     20150328170242  Add topic to posts
   up     20150405212530  Add avatar to users
   up     20150406044601  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20150412173406  Create comments

Kristoffers-MBP:bloccit Juice$ rake db:rollback
Kristoffers-MBP:bloccit Juice$ rake db:migrate:status

database: /Users/Juice/code/bloccit/db/development.sqlite3

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150315080918  Create advertisements
   up     20150321042053  Devise create users
   up     20150323040831  Add role to users
   up     20150328164720  Create topics
   up     20150328170242  Add topic to posts
   up     20150405212530  Add avatar to users
   up     20150406044601  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20150412173406  Create comments

Kristoffers-MBP:bloccit Juice$ rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20150412173406
Kristoffers-MBP:bloccit Juice$ rake db:migrate:status

database: /Users/Juice/code/bloccit/db/development.sqlite3

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150315080918  Create advertisements
   up     20150321042053  Devise create users
   up     20150323040831  Add role to users
   up     20150328164720  Create topics
   up     20150328170242  Add topic to posts
   up     20150405212530  Add avatar to users
   up     20150406044601  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20150412173406  Create comments
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:
rake db:drop

rake db:create

rake db:migrate

Note: all saved data in the database will be lost.

Comment: i'm seeding my own data using gems anyway, so this could be a viable option. thank you for your feedback =]